# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 | can't install throught python and pycharm

Tags: python, suds

I'm setting a bot for VK working with API of pochta.ru 
I cannot install suds because of Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 
setuptools is the latest version

I don't use Linux, I use PyCharm, but through Python it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

For python versions greater than 3.2, You should try using "suds-jurko" instead of "suds".

Comment: ` File "D:/Python/WeatherBot/meh.py", line 28, in <module>
    result = client.service.getOperationHistory(__inject={'msg':message})
  File "D:\Python\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 760, in invoke
    assert msg.__class__ is suds.byte_str_class
AssertionError`

Comment: Please check this following post for this assertion error. It should not be a module error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936558/assertion-error-with-suds

Comment: didn't fixNameError: name 'message' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
  File "D:/Python/WeatherBot/meh.py", line 28, in <module>
result = client.service.getOperationHistory(__inject={'msg':message})
```

File "D:\Python\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in **call**
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 760, in invoke
    assert msg.**class** is suds.byte_str_class
AssertionError